# Thread management

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So I have been trying to write a java program, that involves Threads. It is basically a problem where a thread asks a shared memory resource(cell class in the code below) for permission to move. I'll show you an example of the code in the thread. The three mentioned methods from the cell class are synchronized methods, however they don't implement wait or notify's.

```
public void run() {
    try{
        while(true){
            Random r = new Random();
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(1000));
            //asks the class cell permission to move if the cell is free.
            if(cell.asksAccess(xi, yi, xf, yf)){
                cell.releaseCell(xi, yi); //release the previous cell
                move(); // move the object
                cell.blockCell(xi, yi); // blocks the cell where the object is now staying.
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

private void move() {
    int dx = xf - xi;
    int dy = yf - yi;

    xi += (int) Math.signum(dx);
    yi += (int) Math.signum(dy);
}
```

Like I said before, all the cell class methods invoked are synchronized. My problem is that this is not working as I expected and when I did a sysout to debug, it showed that the threads are not always moving forward and sometimes they even move back to where they were in the beginning and I can't understand why since the move method always tells them to go forward and never back. Is this a sync problem with the cell class? Or is it the move method? Any help would be a lot appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you are not synchronizing the data so all of your threads are reading/writing to local varions of the cell or something.  Hard to tell with the shown code.

Comment: You should move the `Random` outside of the while and move the InterruptedException just around the `Thread.sleep(...);`.  Oh and always at least print the `InterruptedException` and re-interrupt the thread.

Comment: It is 100% possible for a thread to be granted access to a cell, then yield control before any of the steps in your if block are executed. You need to synchronize the entire 'outer' block of logic.

Comment: Could you give me a pratical example please? Perception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets consider the `move` method.  Assuming that:

- the `xi`, `xf`, `yi` and `yf` variables are instance variables of the `Runnable`, and
- there are no other (callback) methods that access or update them,

then we can conclude that those variables are "thread confined" and no synchronization is required.

So where is the problem?  Well I think it is here:

```
if (cell.asksAccess(xi, yi, xf, yf)) {
    cell.releaseCell(xi, yi); //release the previous cell
    move(); // move the object
    cell.blockCell(xi, yi); // blocks the cell where the object is now staying.
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

I can see two issues:

- I think you said that `askCell`, `blockCell` and `releaseCell` synchronize on the `cell` object.  But the problem is that the sequence "ask, block, release" needs to be atomic.
- Your code seems to be releasing a cell(?) at `xi, yi` ... and then blocking it again.  The comments seem to imply that you should be calling `cell.blockCell(xf, yf)` instead.

---

> ... what is the best way to take care of the synchronization of that sequence?

Without seeing the related code, it is hard to say what the best way is.  But *one* way to do it would be to make it one call on the `cell` object ... and deal with the `move` and notifications afterwards; e.g. something like this:

```
if (cell.checkAndMove(xi, yi, xf, yf)) {
    move(); // move the object
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

where `checkAndMove` is defined in the `Cell` class as:

```
public synchronized boolean checkAndMove(int xi, int yi, int xf, int yf) {
    boolean ok = this.asksAccess(xi, yi, xf, yf);
    if (ok) {
        this.releaseCell(xi, yi);
        this.blockCell(xi, yi);
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: I think I got it. Just one more thing, what is the best way to take care of the synchronization of that sequence? Thank you. About the second issue, xi, yi are different in release cell and in block cell, due to the move() method in between that updates the xi and yi.

Comment: That is a good way to aproach the problem and now I think I'll be able to work from this. I can now understand what was wrong before and hopefully won't make the same mistake. Thank you very much for your time, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The private void move() method should be synchronized.

Comment: But the void move() is in the thread, no other thread is going to request access to this move, why does it make a difference if I synchronized the move method?